# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: in android

Tags: android

I have got the SSL certificate for the domain. And also I have created the sub domain under the SSL certified one to host for the several project in this domain. So, I have created the web service then I am trying to get the details from that server. Nut It is throwing the exception like below.

```
09-29 15:03:59.311: W/System.err(26845): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: != <.ipage.com> OR <.ipage.com> OR 
09-29 15:03:59.321: W/System.err(26845): at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:185) 
09-29 15:03:59.321: W/System.err(26845): at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.verify(BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.java:54) 
09-29 15:03:59.321: W/System.err(26845): at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:114) 
09-29 15:03:59.321: W/System.err(26845): at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:95) 
09-29 15:03:59.321: W/System.err(26845): at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:388) 
09-29 15:03:59.321: W/System.err(26845): at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:214) 
09-29 15:03:59.321: W/System.err(26845): at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:167) 
09-29 15:03:59.321: W/System.err(26845): at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:125) 
09-29 15:03:59.321: W/System.err(26845): at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.executeOriginal(DefaultRequestDirector.java:1227) 
09-29 15:03:59.321: W/System.err(26845): at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:677) 
09-29 15:03:59.321: W/System.err(26845): at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:570) 
09-29 15:03:59.321: W/System.err(26845): at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:491) 
09-29 15:03:59.321: W/System.err(26845): at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:469) 
09-29 15:03:59.321: W/System.err(26845): at com.tdzinfo.gamecom.webclient.RequestMethods.callHTTPMethod(RequestMethods.java:38) 
09-29 15:03:59.321: W/System.err(26845): at com.tdzinfo.gamecom.CategoryList$GetProducts.doInBackground(CategoryList.java:74) 
09-29 15:03:59.321: W/System.err(26845): at
```

So, Can anyone suggest me the solution for this, If I use the sub folder in that domain can I have the SSL for this sub domain???

Answer (score 0):

The SSL certificate is linked with a hostname, if the hostname is different, android will throw you  javax.net.ssl.SSLException. You must generate a certificate for that subdomain (hostname)

Comment: is this possible to use same certificate when I am using the sub folder inside the main domain...?? http://example.com/game likewise I am using the folder,

Comment: In the begining yes, you can use a subfolder inside a server with SSL certificate. do you use the correct address in your java code?

Comment: Yes I have used the correct code, Here is my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094381/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-hostname-in-certificate-didnt-match, 

This code is working for the main domain, when I creating the sub folder only I got the above exception.